# Failed to load viewstate error after updating to Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am receiving an error loading viewstate on all my webforms after updating to Visual Studio Service 2010 Pack 1.

**Error message:**

> Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is
>   being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save
>   viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding
>   controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match
>   the type and position of the controls added during the initial
>   request.

Everything was working fine before the upgrade.

Edits:

The problem was actually due to jQuery libaries from google I referenced on my . I removed the runat server on the head, that fixed the problem

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing runat="server" on my master page. That fixed the problem. Masterpage head has some references to Google jQuery files.